# Правильный перенос слова несчастный

Tags: морфемный-разбор, перенос

Разрешите спор. Как правильно перенести -несчаст-ный или несчас-тный? спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Несчаст-ный, так как корень -счаст-, а одну букву от корня отрывать не надо